# How to insert authenticated user id in database without using it in the fillable array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am a beginner in Laravel and following a Laravel tutorial where the instructor is using Laravel 7 while I have Laravel 8 installed. He said we do not want to use user_id in the $fillable array because of security reasons so while creating a new record he used

```
  auth()->user()->stories()->create([

            'title' => $request->title,
            'body' => $request->body,
            'type' => $request->type,
            'status' => $request->status,
           
            
        ]);
```

instead of

```
Story::create([
    
                'title' => $request->title,
                'body' => $request->body,
                'type' => $request->type,
                'status' => $request->status,
                'user_id' =>auth()->id()
                
            ]);
```

but this code is not working for me with the error "Undefined method stories".

Here is my StoriesController

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Story;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StoriesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $stories = Story::where('user_id',auth()->id())->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(4);
       
        return view('stories.index')->with('stories',$stories);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('stories.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        

      

        auth()->user()->stories()->create([

            'title' => $request->title,
            'body' => $request->body,
            'type' => $request->type,
            'status' => $request->status,
            'user_id' =>auth()->id()
            
        ]);

        return redirect('/stories');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Story  $story
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Story $story)
    {
        return view('stories.show',[
            'story' => $story
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Story  $story
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Story $story)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Story  $story
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Story $story)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Story  $story
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Story $story)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Here is the Story Model

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Story extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    protected $fillable = ['title','body','type','status'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(user::class);
    }
}
```

and here is the User Model

```
 <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function stories(){
        return $this->hasMany(Story::class);
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any assistance provided . Thank You

Comment: Why you want avoid to put user_id to the fillable array?

Comment: because we don't want the user to manually input his id as someone can exploit this situation and enter someone else's id. Although this is a practice/dummy app and here it does not matter but i am asking this for the sake of learning and for good coding practice

Comment: Can you edit your question with full error stack? `Undefined method stories` should not occur since, well, you have a method `stories`

Comment: `we don't want the user to manually input his id as someone can exploit this situation and enter someone else's id`. Then don't accept an `id` from the `Request`, you can add `user_id` to `fillable` and then you can be responsible for assigning that value via `auth()->user()->id` or whatever.

Comment: Could you kindly show your stories migration?